# How to enumerate tables in oracle database with LinqPAD IQ Driver?

Tags: oracle, linqpad

I'm trying to enumerate the available tables in my oracle database with LinqPAD. I'm using the IQ driver to connect in direct mode.

On a `Linq to SQL` connection i would be able to execute

```
this.Mapping.GetTables().Select(m => m.TableName)
```

to get a list of all table names, but the context of the IQ driver does not have a `Mappings` property.

Is there another way?